# use IFNULL in laravel

Tags: mysql, php

I have a query in `laravel` which is working fine.

```
$subjects = $app->db->table('subjects')->LeftJoin('downloads', 'subjects.subjectID', '=', 'downloads.subject_id')
        ->where('universityID', $currentUser->universityID)->where('semesterID', $currentUser->semesterID)->where('courseID', $currentUser->courseID)
        ->select('subjects.subjectID', 'subjects.subjectName', 'subjects.price',  'downloads.is_download' )
        ->orderBy('subjectID')
        ->get();
```

There is only one issue that `is_download` comes null when there is no relative entry in table. After some research I found that there is a function `IFNULL` by using which I can change `is_download` `null` to `0`. So here is my query which is not working. Blank screen is showing.

```
$subjects = $app->db->table('subjects')->LeftJoin('downloads', 'subjects.subjectID', '=', 'downloads.subject_id')
        ->where('universityID', $currentUser->universityID)->where('semesterID', $currentUser->semesterID)->where('courseID', $currentUser->courseID)
        ->select('subjects.subjectID', 'subjects.subjectName', 'subjects.price',  IFNULL( `downloads`.`is_download` , 0 ) )
        ->orderBy('subjectID')
        ->get();
```

I am able to write this query in my phpmyadmin but not know how to write in `laravel`

This is the api, So whole code looks like

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression as raw;
use project\Models\Subject;
use project\Models\Semester;
use project\Models\StudentRegistration;

$app->get('/api/getSubject/:studentID', function($studentID) use ($app) {
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $currentUser = StudentRegistration::where('studentID', $studentID)->first();

$subjects = $app->db->table('subjects')->LeftJoin('downloads', 'subjects.subjectID', '=', 'downloads.subject_id')
        ->where('universityID', $currentUser->universityID)->where('semesterID', $currentUser->semesterID)->where('courseID', $currentUser->courseID)
        ->select('subjects.subjectID', 'subjects.subjectName', 'subjects.price',  IFNULL( `downloads`.`is_download` , 0 ) )
        ->orderBy('subjectID')
        ->get();
print_r($subjects);
    return $app->response->write(json_encode([
                'error' => 0,
                'subjects' => $subjects
    ]));
});
```

Comment: `IFNULL` is a SQL function, not a PHP function, so you need to put: `'IFNULL( downloads.is_download , 0 )' ` (ie: with quotes)

Comment: @Phil : `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'IFNULL( downloads.is_download , 0 )'`

Comment: Try: `DB:raw('IFNULL( downloads.is_download , 0 ) as is_download')`

Comment: already tried. Showing blank screen.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a left outer join?

Comment: anything that help me to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
->select('subjects.subjectID', 'subjects.subjectName', 'subjects.price',  
IFNULL( `downloads`.`is_download` , 0 ) )
```

with

```
->select('subjects.subjectID', 'subjects.subjectName', 'subjects.price',  
DB:Raw(' IFNULL( `downloads`.`is_download` , 0 )') )
```

and add an alias

```
->select('subjects.subjectID', 'subjects.subjectName', 'subjects.price',  
DB:Raw(' IFNULL( `downloads`.`is_download` , 0 ) as is_download') )
```